# How do I store a Ruby object in my Rails app without using a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, storing-data

### Given

- This Ruby class:

  ```rb
  class Quiz
    attr_accessor :topic, :course, :highest_grade, :failing_grade, :answers_by_questions

    def initialize(topic, course, highest_grade, failing_grade)
      @topic = topic
      @course = course
      @highest_grade = highest_grade
      @failing_grade = failing_grade
      @answers_by_questions = Hash.new()
    end

    def add_question(question, answer)
      @answers_by_questions[question] = answer
    end
  end
  ```
- This instance of the Quiz class:

  ```rb
  ch1_history_quiz = Quiz.new("Chapter 1", "History", 100, 65)
  ch1_history_quiz.add_question("Which ancient civilisation created the boomerang?", "Aboriginal Australians")
  ```

---

### Objective

Save this quiz object to be accessed later by all users of the app.

---

### Question

How to store and access this quiz object in Rails 6.0 without representing it in a database?

---

### Possible Solutions

- Is it possible to use Marshal to pickle the object and save it to be used later?

---

### What I've checked out so far

[SO - Store json object in ruby on rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831811/store-json-object-in-ruby-on-rails-app): Because this is JSON, going back and forth between the JSON format and the parsed format is more intuitive.

[SO - Can I create a database of ruby classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039811/can-i-create-a-database-of-ruby-classes): I don't really get the answer to this question. Some of the links are broken. I think the question is pretty similar, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Marshal to pickle the object and save it to be
> used later?

Yes, using your same code as example, you could serialize and deserialize the object recovering it just as it was.

```
irb(main):021:0> marshalled = Marshal.dump(ch1_history_quiz)
=> "\x04\bo:\tQuiz\n:\v@topicI\"\x0EChapter 1\x06:\x06ET:\f@courseI\"\fHistory\x06;\aT:\x13@highest_gradeii:\x13@failing_gradeiF:\x1A@answers_by_questions{\x06I\"6Which ancient civilisation created the boomerang?\x06;\aTI\"\eAboriginal Australians\x06;\aT"
irb(main):022:0> deserialized = Marshal.load(marshalled)
=> #<Quiz:0x00007f81d3995348 @topic="Chapter 1", @course="History", @highest_grade=100, @failing_grade=65, @answers_by_questions={"Which ancient civilisation created the boomerang?"=>"Aboriginal Australians"}>
```

Another option, more readable is serializing your object in YAML format:

```
irb(main):030:0> yamled = YAML.dump(ch1_history_quiz)
=> "--- !ruby/object:Quiz\ntopic: Chapter 1\ncourse: History\nhighest_grade: 100\nfailing_grade: 65\nanswers_by_questions:\n  Which ancient civilisation created the boomerang?: Aboriginal Australians\n"
irb(main):031:0> deserialized = YAML.load(yamled)
=> #<Quiz:0x00007f81d398cb80 @topic="Chapter 1", @course="History", @highest_grade=100, @failing_grade=65, @answers_by_questions={"Which ancient civilisation created the boomerang?"=>"Aboriginal Australians"}>
```

With any of both options, you could save it later in a DB text field (with enough space to keep big objects), a plain-text file or whatever you choose.
Also, something very important to keep in mind are [the security issues](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/doc/security_rdoc.html) about using marshal or yaml, so objects must always be loaded from trusted sources.

Comment: Note the second paragraph of the doc for the [Marshal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Marshal.html) module, which discuss portabability among different Ruby versions.